# Ms SQL geography.STDistance return wrong distance

Tags: sql-server, geography

I wnat to calculate the distance between two points like:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
-- lat N 32.05....
-- lon E 34.857.....
SET @g = geography::Point(32.0580450316848, 34.8578243689023, 4326);
SET @h = geography::Point(31.902458291649 ,34.813908168758, 4326);
SELECT @h.STDistance(@g)/1000;
```

The result from the sql is: 17.7447323273369 
The result from Goolge maps is 17.79 KM

I was checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493188/ms-sql-geography-stdistance-returns-wrong-distance) but this is not help to me :(
Any help ?

Comment: Given those coordinates and the Haversine formula, you get 17.79. However, I don't think that the Haversine takes into account that the Earth isn't perfectly round, but rather an oblate (i.e. squished along the polar axis) spheroid. That could account for the ≈ 16m difference.

Comment: SQL Server is the one outputting the correct value. Google/Bing Maps are not made for precision.

Comment: Why the sql server is correct and google is not ? I don't think that google will use with wrong formula and so on microsoft. with whom should I trust?

Comment: SQL Server is more correct because Microsoft is using Vincenty's formulae instead of the Haversince formula.  I recently solved this one myself here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159104/why-is-there-a-difference-in-sqlgeography-stdistance/46373111#46373111

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will use your code in my code.